# Spring Boot Why are my changes to the application.properties not being saved?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a test Spring project in which I have a few routes mapped to the views from the controllers, my problem is that every time I close or execute a change in my project the port is changed to 8080 (Spring default port) , but I already occupy that port and I need to use 8081

When I write:

```
server.port=8081
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.forms</groupId>
<artifactId>forms-java</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>forms-java</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>18</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

in my application.properties the port changes correctly, until I make and save a change to the models or source code. How do I fix this?

Comment: Need more information on how you are saving and/or how you are using this port

Comment: Check the build system, if its overriding the default properties, Share pom.xml or build.gradle files here.

Comment: Can you show the exact project structure and where the file is located in that structure? I have a feeling, that you are editing an application.yml, that's located in the output folder of your project, which would be overwritten on compilation.

Comment: I just added the pom.xml, as you can see I use devtools, validation and spring boot stater webs.